# Installing Debian 7 (Wheezy) on VMWare Fusion

Tags: debian, boot, vmware

I'm trying to install Debian 7 x64 on to VMWare Fusion Professional 7.0.1 (on Mac OS X 10.10.1):
I downloaded debian-7.7.0-ia64-netinst.iso and tried to start a VM with it and got the following:

[image: vmwareerror]
After which, VMWare said that the CPU was disabled by the guest operating system.

The image was downloaded from: http://caesar.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/7.7.0/ia64/iso-cd/debian-7.7.0-ia64-netinst.iso

When I created the VM, I used "Debian 7.x 64-bit" as the option for the operating system.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: just wondering...do the md5sums match up?

Comment: I think so: **`md5 *.iso`**
`MD5 (debian-7.7.0-ia64-DVD-1.iso) = 340c3efbecfe6222d7b98a042fd4b6b7`
`MD5 (debian-7.7.0-ia64-netinst.iso) = 0292d5538a51a3f5d1ab99c555dd9709`

Comment: Debian i386 seems to work fine.  I suppose VMWare has a problem with the 64-bit boot loader...

Comment: I'm having the same issue... I created the machine using Debian 7 64bits and download net install and full vertion both return same error (the funny screen on top)

Comment: Try the `amd64` version instead, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the amd64 version if you need x64. They should be working.

In your case from http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.7.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-7.7.0-amd64-netinst.iso

Answer (score 0):

I called VMWare, who said it was *unsupported*.  As a result, they gave me a refund, and the link to request it as a feature in the next release...  The 32-bit version works however.  My guess is one could do some debugging of the GRUB boot-loader to figure out what is really happening.